# Python Flask how not to include one specific element in a query sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I want to find all books with the same category as a given book.  Right now, my query includes the specific book as well, but I only want *other* books.  How do I exclude the specific book from the query?

```
@app.route('/book/<id>')
def book(id):
    return render_template(
        'book.html',
        specific_book=Book.query.filter_by(id=id).first(),
        category_books=Book.query.filter_by(category=(Book.query.filter_by(id=id).first()).category).limit(9)
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a filter to your query to exclude that id.

```
@app.route('/book/<id>')
def book(id):
    book = Book.query.get_or_404(id)
    related = Book.query.filter(Book.id != id, Book.category == book.category)
    return render_template('book.html', book=book, related=related)
```

`filter_by` is just a shortcut for equality filters, where kwargs are converted to attributes on the current selectable.  If you need something besides equality (such as inequality), you use the normal `filter` method.

This is described in the SQLAlchemy docs' [tutorial on queries](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#querying).